# Is there a way to upload GitLab CI artifacts to an Openshift container?

Tags: gitlab, openshift, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab CI pipeline which builds a few artifacts. For example:

```
train:job:
  stage: train
  script: python script.py
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - artifact.csv
    expire_in: 1 week
```

Now I deploy the repository to OpenShift using the following step in my GitLab pipeline. This will pull my GitLab repo inside OpenShift. It does not include the artifacts from the 'testing'.

```
deploy:app:
  stage: deploy
  image: ayufan/openshift-cli
  before_script:
    - oc login $OPENSHIFT_DOMAIN --token=$OPENSHIFT_TOKEN
  script:
    - oc start-build my_app
```

How can I let OpenShift use this repository, plus the artifacts created in my pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general OpenShift [build pipelines](https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/builds/index.html) rely on the [s2i](https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image) build process to build applications.

The best practice for reusing artifacts between s2i builds would either be through using [incremental builds](https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image#incremental-builds) or chaining multiple BuildConfig definitions (the output image of one BuildConfig being fed as source image into another BuildConfig) together via the `spec.source.images` or `spec.source.git` configuration in the [BuildConfig definition](https://docs.okd.io/latest/rest_api/apis-build.openshift.io/v1.BuildConfig.html).

In your case since you are using a Jenkins pipeline to generate your artifacts instead of the OpenShift build process you really only need to combine your artifacts with your source code and the runtime container image.

To do this you might create a builder container image that pulls those artifacts down from an external source during the [assemble](https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image/blob/master/docs/builder_image.md#assemble) phase (via curl, wget, etc) of the s2i workflow. You could then configure your BuildConfig to point at your source repository. At build time the BuildConfig will pull down your source code and the assemble script will pull down your artifacts.